# Facebook Page Events are no more available also other calls are restricted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The graph call for Facebook page events using user access token is not giving any page events. The call was working fine till yesterday, dated : 11th April 2018.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/spatsberkeley/events?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

https://www.facebook.com/pg/spatsberkeley/events/?ref=page_internal

Referring to below links, it says that Facebook is going to restrict API calls and information available through it. What kind of permissions user will have to accept to allow page events graph call work ? Also its mentioned that few graph calls and FB login calls will be restricted, but specific date when it will stop working is not mentioned :

https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/9-important-changes-facebook-is-making-to-restrict-data-access-1833020

https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/facebook-instagram-api-shut-down/?utm_medium=TCnewsletter

https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes shows you what they recently disabled. Some of that might be temporary, but for now you will just have to wait until there’s actual news on that from Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe For Page events call nothing is mentioned , https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-4 , 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

Comment: When it specifically says here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4, that “all apps, including formerly approved apps, must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the API” regarding the Events node, then I don’t think you can expect to get events from a specific page either right now ...

Comment: @CBroe do you know what one needs to do for read-only access to events? App Review process seems to have only things that require login (e.g. see users, edit event, etc). Would be a HUGE help!

Comment: Again, quoting from one of the big fat notes they placed in the documentation: _"Apps accessing the Events API and Groups API will lose access and require review **once App Review resumes**. For apps using Pages API, review will be required **once App Review resumes** or access will be removed."_ (highlights by me) Facebook themselves have not figured this out yet, so you just will have to be patient until they have some news to announce regarding review. There currently is no way to submit for this, hence _once App Review resumes._